# How will the messiah deal with Khazars and Sabbateans, who falsely claim to be Jews?

Tags: messiah

How will the messiah deal with Khazars and Sabbateans, who are no Jews and falsely claim to be Jews?

Comment: Probably treat them as non-Jews. Do any of them still exist?

Comment: Hello Andromeda. Welcome to Mi Yodeya! The Sabbatean movement mostly died out in the 18th century. Any descendants of theirs would be Jewish if their mothers were Jewish (and they would be Jewish if their mothers were Jewish...). The Khazars (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khazars#Judaism)) apparently converted to Judaism many centuries ago. If so, they would be full Jews, and again, anyone today whose mother's mother's mother...Was one of them, would be Jewish.

Comment: For more about the criteria to be Jewish (matrilineal descent or conversion) see: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52891/am-i-jewish

Comment: @mevaqesh, do you have a definitive answer to [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60661/will-moshiach-identify-jews-currently-thought-to-be-non-jews) or are you just assuming?

Comment: @Andromeda At this point in history, even those of the Khazar empire who converted have now married into legitimate Jewish families, and thereby have Jewish genetics that are proven via DNA testing. It is no longer a fair assessment to claim they are not Jewish. You can claim that they have a much smaller percentage than say Yemenite Jews, but that is a different argument.

Comment: @Andromeda The book of Revelations is a Christian book. I don't know the context of that verse and I don't understand it, but it doesn't matter because that book is not part of the Jewish canon.

Answer (score 2):

At this point in history, even those of the Khazar empire who converted have now married into legitimate Jewish families, and thereby have Jewish genetics that are proven via DNA testing. It is no longer a fair assessment to claim they are not Jewish. You can claim that they have a much smaller percentage than say Yemenite Jews, but that is a different argument.

As for the verse you mentioned in your comments, Revelation 3:9

> I will make those who are of the synagogue of Satan, who claim to be Jews though they are not, but are liars--I will make them come and fall down at your feet and acknowledge that I have loved you.

i would argue this refers to Christians who have created their own religion, separate from Judaism (remember, at this point in history, Christians go to Synagogues as well). They claim to be "the new spiritual Israel" but keep almost none of the commandments, desecrate the holy Sabbath day, and don't wear tzith-tzith. Remember, on the great day of the LORD, everyone will know who is with God, those who wear tzith tzith

Zechariah 8:23

> כג  כֹּה-אָמַר, יְהוָה צְבָאוֹת, בַּיָּמִים הָהֵמָּה, אֲשֶׁר
>   יַחֲזִיקוּ עֲשָׂרָה אֲנָשִׁים מִכֹּל לְשֹׁנוֹת הַגּוֹיִם; וְהֶחֱזִיקוּ
>   בִּכְנַף אִישׁ יְהוּדִי לֵאמֹר, נֵלְכָה עִמָּכֶם--כִּי שָׁמַעְנוּ,
>   אֱלֹהִים עִמָּכֶם.  {ס}   23 Thus saith the LORD of hosts: In those
>   days it shall come to pass, that ten men shall take hold, out of all
>   the languages of the nations, shall even take hold of the corner of
>   his garment (where the tzith tzith are) of him that is a Jew, saying:
>   We will go with you, for we have heard that God is with you.'

This might even include Khazars or Sabbateans who wear tzith tzith

Answer (score 1):

There is a story about the khazars having converted to Judaism. If true they were never false Jews but converts. Converts are accepted as being fully Jewish. Regardless, they were killed and have no surviving offspring today. The shabatai tzvi movement ended when he converted to Islam. As for your quote from something called revelations, this isn't a Jewish source and isn't relevant to anything the Torah has to say about the Messiah