Jews who turn out to be non-Jewish in the age of Moshiach
I remember a chaver from yeshiva mentioning an obscure passage on what becomes of the non-Jew who, having mistakenly lived his entire life as an observant Jew, learns that he was not actually ever Jewish. It involved Eliyahu ha-Navi, but I cannot remember all the details. Could anyone help? Thank you and a gut'n Shabbos.

Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Fascinating question. Based on the high quality of the question, I suspect you've already seen the site tour and know how this site is unique. Looking forward to learning with you in future. BTW, you might find this question also interesting as it's the complement/mirror of your question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60661/will-moshiach-identify-jews-currently-thought-to-be-non-jews?rq=1

See the last Mishna in Eduyot. It doesn't quite address this, but does address those who were deemed "eligible to marry Jewish bluebloods" and those who weren't; is it Eliyahu's job to clear that up? https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Eduyot.8.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

You start with "an observant non-Jew". What makes a person Jewish - is it being or status? Is Jewishness an internal characteristic, like being male or female, or an external status, like citizenship? The ruling Halachah does not say anything about being a Jew but only about one's Halachic status - whether one can be considered Halachicly Jewish in a given community.

So my understanding of Rambam’s view, is that while neither Eliyahoo nor the Moshiah would actively sort people out, the truth will become evident  https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.12.2?vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he

@Shalom That is probably the correct source. It is also brought in Kiddushin 71a. Saying it refers to non-Jews is probably a mistake.
